# My "drawView" function is being called only once?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to OpenGL ES and having a simple kind of problem in my project. I've successfully drawn a square on my screen but the problem is that my "drawView" function in my EAGLView is 
only called once however I wrote code to call it again n again as in Xcode's OpenGL ES Template.

Do anyone have clue where's the mistake?

Following is the code of my EAGLView.m file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>

#import "EAGLView.h"

#define USE_DEPTH_BUFFER 0

// A class extension to declare private methods
@interface EAGLView ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) EAGLContext *context;
- (BOOL) createFramebuffer;
- (void) destroyFramebuffer;
@end


@implementation EAGLView

@synthesize context;
@synthesize animating;
@dynamic animationFrameInterval;


// You must implement this method
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

//The GL view is stored in the nib file. When it's unarchived it's sent -initWithCoder:
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {

    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
        // Get the layer
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

        eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
        eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

        if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }

        animating = FALSE;
        displayLinkSupported = FALSE;
        animationFrameInterval = 1;
        displayLink = nil;
        animationTimer = nil;

        // A system version of 3.1 or greater is required to use CADisplayLink. The NSTimer
        // class is used as fallback when it isn't available.
        NSString *reqSysVer = @"3.1";
        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
            displayLinkSupported = TRUE;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawView {
    NSLog(@"In EAGLView's drawView func");

    static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -0.5f,  -0.33f,
        0.5f,  -0.33f,
        -0.5f,   0.33f,
        0.5f,   0.33f,
    };

    static const GLubyte squareColors[] = {
        255, 0, 0, 255,
        0, 255, 0, 255,
        0, 0, 255, 255,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
    };

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, squareVertices);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, squareColors);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    [self destroyFramebuffer];
    [self createFramebuffer];
    [self drawView];
}

- (BOOL)createFramebuffer {
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    if (USE_DEPTH_BUFFER) {
        glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
        glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
        glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
    }

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)destroyFramebuffer {
    glDeleteFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    viewFramebuffer = 0;
    glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
    viewRenderbuffer = 0;

    if(depthRenderbuffer) {
        glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        depthRenderbuffer = 0;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)animationFrameInterval
{
    return animationFrameInterval;
}

- (void)setAnimationFrameInterval:(NSInteger)frameInterval
{
    // Frame interval defines how many display frames must pass between each time the
    // display link fires. The display link will only fire 30 times a second when the
    // frame internal is two on a display that refreshes 60 times a second. The default
    // frame interval setting of one will fire 60 times a second when the display refreshes
    // at 60 times a second. A frame interval setting of less than one results in undefined
    // behavior.
    if (frameInterval >= 1)
    {
        animationFrameInterval = frameInterval;

        if (animating)
        {
            [self stopAnimation];
            [self startAnimation];
        }
    }
}

- (void)startAnimation
{
    if (!animating)
    {
        if (displayLinkSupported)
        {
            // CADisplayLink is API new to iPhone SDK 3.1. Compiling against earlier versions will result in a warning, but can be dismissed
            // if the system version runtime check for CADisplayLink exists in -initWithCoder:. The runtime check ensures this code will
            // not be called in system versions earlier than 3.1.

            displayLink = [NSClassFromString(@"CADisplayLink") displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(drawView)];
            [displayLink setFrameInterval:animationFrameInterval];
            [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        }
        else
            animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)((1.0 / 60.0) * animationFrameInterval) target:self selector:@selector(drawView) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];

        animating = TRUE;
    }
}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
    if (animating)
    {
        if (displayLinkSupported)
        {
            [displayLink invalidate];
            displayLink = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            [animationTimer invalidate];
            animationTimer = nil;
        }

        animating = FALSE;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == context) {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
    }

    [context release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: This is the screenshot of the project in iphone simulator:
http://img814.imageshack.us/img814/8377/screenshot20100818at112.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if your method:

```
- (void)startAnimation
```

is actually being called.

Comment: Hey, Thnx 4 replying.
The problem was exactly what u said.
There wasn't any problem in the current code file. However, I was not calling the startAnimation function from AppDelegate class. =)